# How do I centre a gltf model of the viewport in threejs?

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I'm new to threejs and I've been having an issue with both moving an imported gltf model and moving the camera around the model. My goal is to have the model fit within the canvas dead in the centre. But currently the model seems to be cut off at the top.
if I set `camera.up.set(0,0,0)`. I get the result I want but with the trade-off that the orbit controls don't behave how I wanted them to.

I've tried changing the `camera.position.y` but that seems to rotate around a point and eventually just gives me a top down view of my model.

**This is how it currently looks with the below code:**

[image]

**This is how I want it to look but without having to set** `camera.up.set(0, 0, 0)`
[image]

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import * as THREE from 'three';
const GarlicSan = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      45,
      266 / 400,
      45,
      4000
    );
    camera.position.set(
     0, 300, 1000
    )
    //camera.up.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    const canvas = document.getElementById('garlic'); 
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas, antialias: true});
    const updateCanvas = () => {
      renderer.setSize( 266, 400);
      document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    };
    updateCanvas();
    // controls

    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.enableDamping = true;
    controls.enablePan = true;

    //model loader
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    loader.load('/chibi_garlic/scene.gltf', (gltf) => {
      scene.add(gltf.scene)
      renderer.render(scene, camera)
    });

    renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0);
    const animate = () => {
      controls.update();
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    };
    animate();
  }, []);

  const type = useSelector((state) => state.content)
  return(
    <>
    { type.content === 'lobby' ? (

      <canvas className=' absolute z-50 left-0 right-0 mx-auto top-[20%]' id='garlic'></canvas>
    ) : ( <canvas className=' absolute z-50 left-1 transition-all' id='garlic'></canvas>
 )}
    </>
  )
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has this issue. When using orbit controls the target is set to 0, 0, 0. so when changing the camera position the camera will move its x,y,z around that target. My model was placed on top of the 0, 0, 0 mark so I set the `controls.target.set(0, 300, 0)` once I had defined controls.